# how to add function and put it peremeter to return result ? python

Tags: python

i want to creat a function to return a result if i put inside is 2 peremeter to get there ?

### this code :

```
num1 = int(input('put the number 1 : '))
num2 = int(input('put the number 2 : '))

def permitation(n1,n2):
    nn1 = n1
    n1 = n2
    n2 = nn1
    return num1,num2


permitation(num1,num2)


print('num1 : {}'.format(num1))
print('num2 : {}'.format(num2))
```

### output :

```
put the number 1 : 10
put the number 2 : 1
num1 : 10
num2 : 1
```

but i need :

```
put the number 1 : 10
put the number 2 : 1
num1 : 1
num2 : 10
```

> help me plz

Answer (score 2):

I thought I had a stroke reading the question and the answer hs

```
num1, num2 = num2, num1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all these extra variables:

```
def swap(n1, n2):
    return n2, n1

num1, num2 = swap(num1, num2)
```

Of course, you don't need a function for this at all.

```
num1, num2 = num2, num1
```